# multiple rows with the same maximum value

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

When I run the following query,

```
SELECT engines, manufacturer, model, MAX(seats)
FROM   planes
GROUP BY engines;
```

I am getting the correct engines and seats results but not the correct manufacturer, model combination. In addition, there are multiple rows with the same maximum value for seats number which I need but just getting one result by engines/seats. I have viewed other Stack Exchange posts and elsewhere but cannot seem to find a good solution to fix the query. Any advice?

Comment: Your query is invalid SQL because the `group by` is incorrect. But MySQL choses to return random (they call it indeterminate) data instead. See e.g. here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/ or here: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html for details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yours appears to be a "greatest N per group" problem. What you can do is get the maximum seats per engine results:

```
SELECT
  engines,
  MAX(seats) AS max_seats
FROM
  planes
GROUP BY
  engines
```

and, using them as a derived table, join them back to the source to get the rows matching the maximums:

```
SELECT
  p.engines,
  p.manufacturer,
  p.model,
  es.max_seats
FROM
  planes AS p
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      engines,
      MAX(seats) AS max_seats
    FROM
      planes
    GROUP BY
      engines
  ) AS es
  ON p.engines = es.engines
  AND p.seats = es.max_seats
;
```

Comment: The join reconciles the correct info as @Lennart's query did too...

Comment: @GMode: His answer also does a really good job of explaining what was wrong with your original query – much superior to the one you chose to accept, if you pardon my forwardness.

Comment: @Andriy..pardoned. All responses/queries did really good jobs to increase my understanding of where I went awry. Also pardon my newness to the stackexchange.com community.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have more columns in the select than in the group by. This is allowed with default settings in MySQL, but may lead to in-deterministic results. Example:

```
engines, manufacturer, model, seats
A        A            A       10
A        B            C       20
```

Your query:

```
SELECT engines, manufacturer, model, MAX(seats)
FROM   planes
GROUP BY engines;
```

then means, "get the max number of seats for engine 'A' and randomly pick a manufacturer/model for 'A'. This could mean:

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
| engines | manufacturer | model | MAX(seats) |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
| A       | A            | B     |         20 |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
```

but could just as well have been:

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
| engines | manufacturer | model | MAX(seats) |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
| A       | B            | C     |         20 |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
```

You can prevent this by requiring a full group by:

```
MariaDB [test]> set @@sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'
-> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT engines, manufacturer, model,  MAX(seats)     FROM   planes     GROUP BY engines;
ERROR 1055 (42000): 'test.planes.manufacturer' isn't in GROUP BY
```

If you want the manufacturer/model for the engine with most seats you can first get the max seats for the engine, and then join the original table as in @Andriy M answer:

```
SELECT A.engines, B.manufacturer, B.model, A.seats 
from (
    SELECT engines, MAX(seats) as seats    
    FROM   planes     
    GROUP BY engines
) as A 
join planes B 
    on A.engines = B.engines 
   and A.seats = B.seats;

+---------+--------------+-------+-------+
| engines | manufacturer | model | seats |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------+
| A       | B            | C     |    20 |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------+
```

Other DBMS such as PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2 and SQL-Server provides window functions that makes this kind of query easier:

```
select engines, manufacturer, model, seats
from (
    select engines, manufacturer, model, seats
         , row_number() over (partition by engine
                              order by seats desc) as rn
    from planes
) where rn = 1;
```

Comment: +1. The indeterminate result could even be from multiple rows (in some rare cases), eg. : `A B A 20` ... !

Comment: The join reconciles the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have columns in the select that are not grouped by and not aggregated.

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly but if you want one row for every Engine/Manufacturer/Model with the max seats in that grouping, you should add them to the group by.

Comment: Amir..my task is..What are the diff #s of engines in the planes table? For each # of engines, which aircraft have the most # of seats?